# Need example for try-catch-finally where finally is a must

Tags: powershell, scripting

I need an example that use `try..catch..finally` clause where the `finally` is **NECESSARY** vs `try..catch` clause where `finally` is optional.  The example below only demonstrated that `finally` is optional because with or without it, it won't make any different to my output.

My Example (note: `$ErrorActionPreference` is `Continue`):

```
try {
    $value = 5 / 0 
} catch {
    Write-Output "illegal operation"
}
$t = Get-Date
Write-Output ("operation is done at " + "$t")
```

The reason is I need to know where `finally` clause become necessary vs just put `finally` clause no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

A `finally` clause is just a logical construct saying "this statement or group of statements should always be run at the end of the `try` block, regardless of whether there was an error or not". It tells people reading the code that there is a logical connection between the code in the `try` and `finally` blocks (e.g. opening and closing a database connection). However, beyond that there is no essential difference between

```
try {
    5 / 0 
} catch {
    'illegal operation'
}
'continued'
```

and

```
try {
    5 / 0 
} catch {
    'illegal operation'
} finally {
    'continued'
}
```

You can find some discussion of the subject [here](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/1914).

I think the only way it would make a difference is if you return or exit in the `try` block:

```
try {
    'foo'    # <-- displayed
    exit
} finally {
    'bar'    # <-- displayed
}
'baz'        # <-- not displayed
```

but maybe something like that is just bad design.

Comment: hi Ansgar, Agreed on the bad design part on your third example. that `'baz'` will not be executed no matter what happen above it.

Comment: It's just an example. The exit could be conditional for instance, but I'd still consider it bad design.